# when use two class in xml give error unbound prefix error

Tags: android

I want to use two class in xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:wave="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<com.example.tesst.MaskableFrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frm_mask_animated"
android:layout_width="100dp"
app:porterduffxfermode="DST_IN"
app:mask="@drawable/animation_mask"
android:layout_height="100dp">

<com.john.waveview.WaveView
    android:id="@+id/wave_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    wave:above_wave_color="@android:color/white"
    wave:blow_wave_color="@android:color/white"
    wave:progress="80"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    wave:wave_height="little"
    wave:wave_hz="normal"
    wave:wave_length="middle" />
</com.example.tesst.MaskableFrameLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

What is wrong with it? The error:Error parsing XML: unbound prefix shows up!
I do not know what is the problem
Help please

Comment: Close your MaskableFrameLayout: `<com.example.tesst.MaskableFrameLayout ..... />` and don't forget to do that for the parent FrameLayout at the end: `</FrameLayout>`

Comment: Thanks .The problem is something else. I put the code in full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the "app:" prefix, and that's not defined.

Change

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:wave="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

To

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:wave="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```